# "is willing to" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have looked up in the Cambridge's dictionary and have found this definition

> ***be willing (to do sth)*** : to be happy to do something if it is needed

But ***is willing to*** in this context don't mean like that, does it?

> Three months. That’s as long as Dr. Anthony Fauci, director of the
>   National Institute of Allergy and Infectious Diseases at the National
>   Institutes of Health, ***is willing to*** wait to get a vaccine candidate
>   against the latest coronavirus that he can start testing in people.

Source : https://time.com/5775784/coronavirus-vaccine-research/

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with the Cambridge definition. There is a difference in meaning between:

I am willing to do the dishes (it is a task I would do if needed)
I am happy to do the dishes (I would be glad to do this task)

or

I am willing to pay my taxes (I agree it's necessary or fear consequences)
I am happy to pay my taxes (I think the benefits are worth it or I'm glad to have a income, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "happy to do so" and "willing to do so" is in degree, or [connotation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/connotation), rather than the "simple" meaning, or [denotation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/denotation?s=t). Think of it as a continuum or spectrum from *really* desiring something to just suffering without complaint.

- Craving to  `Yes, yes! I want this!`
- Yearning to
- Eager to
- Wanting to
- Glad to
- Happy to
- Amenable to  `It's OK.`
- Willing to
- Consenting to
- Acquiesce to
- Resigned to
- Submit to  `You're going to force me to do this, so there's no point in protesting.`

> He has a craving to eat ice cream.

> She wants to get good grades.

> He is willing to go to the doctor, if he doesn't feel better.

> She'll acquiesce to wearing her sister's clothes, but prefers her own.

> He'll submit to the blood test, but would rather not.

[One certainly can argue about the order of synonyms in that "spectrum", which was given only to illustrate the concept.]

Comment: Where would you put "happy to" on that list? If it's in the same place as "willing to", then the Cambridge definition is correct. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: No, "willing to do so," has the mild connotation of conceding, i.e., would do so, but perhaps slightly begrudgingly. "Happy to" implies the person is *happy*, actually glad, to do so. "I'd be willing to lend you $5," but I'm not thrilled with the prospect. "I'd be happy to finish your desert," and I'll enjoy it.

Comment: My point is that without "happy to" somewhere on that list, you haven't answered the OP's question.